# AngularJS ui-select dynamic group filtering

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I couldn't find a web example of this, it appears to me as if the group-filter attribute option of a ui-select doesn't support dynamic changes? If I pass in an array directly e.g.:

```
<ui-select-choices group-filter="['A', 'B', 'C']" ... >
```

It works fine, however if that array is instead a scope variable:

```
$scope.filterArray = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
...
<ui-select-choices group-filter="filterArray" ... >
```

No filtering occurs. I'm wondering if this is a bug or a concious design choice. I'd like to be able to modify the array to update what groups are hidden/shown but currently it doesn't look like that's possible.

Official ui-select group-filter plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/KHSy5VRh9z6o5gs9QOc4?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

`group-filter`property accepts only string or function as parameter. So in your second example `ui-select` will be looking for a function `$scope.filterArray()` in your controller and not a variable.

[Click here for Documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-choices#example-grouping)